# Someone has experience with container content elements, DCEs and Frontend Editing in TYPO3 v10?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I am experiencing a problem with container content elements and content elements.

I wonder whether you can configure TYPO3, so it's possible to add content elements via drag and drop into a container in the frontend editor? For example you have a container with 2 columns, left and right, so that you can add a content element in each column?

It seems to be buggy and not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the Fluid code you have and maybe some screenshots for easier debugging?

But in general the drag and drop should work.

Comment: thx for your reply. 

Pls check this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68942916/someone-with-experience-in-typo3-v10-frontend-editing-and-gridelements

here are some more informations. And the drag and drop is only partly working. I can only insert content elements above the content element that is already is the grid element. However, I am not able to insert one element below that element. Because those elements get the colPos of -1.

And I did not use any fluid code.