# Someone with experience in TYPO3 v10 Frontend_editing and gridelements?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-gridelements

By using this example

https://gist.github.com/joekolade/674ecba5c2615901581d6c4e4c272b4a

I want to be able to use a grid content element and place content elements via drag and drop in the frontend_editor.

The problem is that it is not working, due to the fact that in line 49 in the DropzoneModifier, the parameter -1 is used , which is the value of the colPos for the content element in the grid element. That makes no sense and this leads to:

CEs I'm trying to put in the grid element get the colPos of -1 and due to that, are not placed within the grid element
[image]

Also, watch here: all have colPos=-1

[image]

Any ideas on how to use a variable value for colPos rather than constantly using -1? How to do that programmatically?